# Liferay 6.2 IDE - JSP validation - Type not found

Tags: eclipse, jsp, ide, liferay-6

I'm porting a portlet plugin from 6.1 to 6.2 Liferay platform

In Liferay IDE, in JSP files I have a validation problem, due the fact that I have several yellow exclamation point for example in the below code:

```
<param name ="host" value = "<%= cs.getAs400Url() %>" />
```

The content in the "value" argument is underlined in yellow and the validation error is "- Type "<%= cs.getAs400Url() %>" not found."

The same error for example in the below code:

```
<liferay-portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/ManageDossier/passeggero-view.jsp" />
```

The error is "Type "/html/ManageDossier/passeggero-view.jsp" not found."

### My environment:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
- Liferay IDE 2.2.1.201411200728-ga2

Please, anyone could help me ?

Thank you in advance !

Ivano C.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the jsp validation in eclipse, you can disable it:

- Open Project properties -> Validation
- Check "Enable project specific settings"
- Uncheck "JSP References Validator"